# Find consecutive dates in a dataframe, grouped by another column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

So the point is to find the Person who entered on 3 consecutive dates.
My frame looks like this:

```
        DateEntry    Person
1       2018-03-18   A
2       2018-03-19   A
3       2018-03-21   A
4       2018-09-25   B
5       2018-09-26   B
6       2018-09-27   B
```

The only way I know how to check this is by changing the dates into a list of strings and then checking.
It works fine, but, this method is not allowed.

Is there a way to iterate through the rows on a dataframe via pandas to find the answer?

I'm only expected to show the following output. I do not need to save the results within the dataframe.
Expected output:

```
Person A did not enter on 3 consecutive days.

Person B did enter on three consecutive days.
Consecutive days entered by person B:
2018-09-25
2018-09-26
2018-09-27
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected output here? Will the DateEntry column always be sorted? Will there always be at least three entries for the same person in a row?

Comment: I edited it to show expected output now. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: There are always 3 values per groups?

Comment: Not necessarily, some other persons, let's say C and D have entries with 4-5 dates. I just need to find the people who entered at least 3 days. So >=3.

Comment: Super, so my answer should working nice. If need also datetimes, working for solution.

Comment: I test answer again and added better one, also added solution for datetimes, please check answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If datetimes are sorted and expected output is only check if 3 consecutive dates in days use [strides](https://rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html) in custom function in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df['DateEntry'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateEntry'])

def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

def f(x):
    vals = rolling_window(x.to_numpy(), 3)
    dif = np.diff(vals, axis=1).astype("timedelta64[D]")==np.array([1], dtype='timedelta64[D]')
    #print (dif)

    return dif.all(axis=1).any()

s = df.groupby('Person')['DateEntry'].apply(f)
print (s)
Person
A    False
B     True
Name: DateEntry, dtype: bool
```

If need also datetimes:

```
print (df)
    DateEntry Person
1  2018-03-18      A
2  2018-03-19      A
3  2018-03-21      A
4  2018-08-25      B
5  2018-08-26      B
6  2018-08-27      B
7  2018-09-25      B
8  2018-09-26      B
9  2018-09-27      B
10 2018-09-30      B
```

---

```
df['DateEntry'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateEntry'])
df = df.sort_values(['Person','DateEntry'])

def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

def f(x):
    vals = rolling_window(x.to_numpy(), 3)
    dif = np.diff(vals, axis=1).astype("timedelta64[D]")==np.array([1], dtype='timedelta64[D]')

    return pd.DataFrame(vals[dif.all(axis=1)])
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby('Person')['DateEntry'].apply(f)
print (df1)
                  0          1          2
Person                                   
B      0 2018-08-25 2018-08-26 2018-08-27
       1 2018-09-25 2018-09-26 2018-09-27
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data =[['2018-03-18', 'A'],
       ['2018-03-19', 'A'],
       ['2018-03-21', 'A'],
       ['2018-09-25', 'B'],
       ['2018-09-26', 'B'],
       ['2018-09-27', 'B']]
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['DateEntry', 'Person'])

Person = None
Date = None
count = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if Person:
        if Person == row['Person']:
            count += 1
        else:
            Person = row['Person']
            Date = None
            count = 0
    else:
        Person = row['Person']
        count += 1

    if Date:
        if (datetime.strptime(row['DateEntry'], "%Y-%m-%d") - datetime.strptime(Date, "%Y-%m-%d")).days == 1:
            Date = row['DateEntry']
            if count == 3:
                print('The consecutive visitor is -- {}'.format(Person))
        else:
            Person = None
            Date = None
            count = 0
    else:
        Date = row['DateEntry']
```